Proving that $s \sim t$ iff $S\vdash s = t$ is an equivalence relation.
As part of a proof of Gödel's Completeness Theorem, we have to show that $s \sim t$ iff $S\vdash s = t$ is an equivalence relation. I was wondering if this could be done by natural deduction using the rules $\def\tI{\text{intro}} \def\tE{\text{elim}}$
$$\frac{}{( t = t)}(=\tI)
\ \ \ \ \text{ and } \ \ \ \
\frac{\phi[s\setminus x]\ \ \ \ (s = t)}{\phi[t\setminus x]},\frac{\phi[s\setminus x]\ \ \ \ (t = s)}{\phi[t\setminus x]}(=\tE).$$
Proof (?):

Reflexivity: the rule $(=\tI)$ allows us to prove $(t = t)$ for any term $t$.
Symmetry: suppose $S\vdash (s = t)$, then
$$\frac{(s = s)\ \ \ \ (s = t)}{(t = s)}(=\tE)$$
where we have substituted the first instance of $s$ in the sentence $(s = s)$ by $t$.
Transitivity: suppose $S \vdash (s = t), (t = u)$, then
$$\frac{(s = t)\ \ \ \ (t = u)}{(s = u)}(=\tE)$$
where we have substituted the instance of $t$ in $(s = t)$ by $u$.


Here is my formal proof using a form of natural deduction that formally specifies the domain of discourse: https://dcproof.com/EqualityEquivalenceRelation.htm

Long comment
Yes, the approach is the right one: you have to use reflexivity, symmetry and transitivty of equality to show that the above relation between terms is an equivalence relation.
I've only some small concerns regarding the correct use of the ND rules.
Re symmetry, we have to show that $s=t$ implies $t=s$.
In order to use the $(= \text {elim})$ rule, we have to use $(x=s)$ as $\phi$. Thus, $\phi[s/x]$ will be $s=s$ and $\phi[t/x]$ will be the sought $t=s$.
The same for transitivity, with $(x=u)$ as $\phi$.
